# How to unpatch a method in a Javascript object? Specifically XMLHttpRequest.open

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, closures, monkeypatching

We have a React application where someone has patched the XMLHttpRequest.open method to something like this:

```
const token = ....
let xhrPrevOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (...a) {
    xhrPrevOpen.apply(this, [ ...a ]);
    this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
};
```

Apparently this was done to include the authorization header by default in all http requests across the application, saving one additional line of code everytime someone needs to make a request.

One downside of this thing is that we have some use cases where we want to make requests to external apis (cross domain) which require their own Authorization headers. Adding another authorization header by default does not help as it appends the header instead of replacing it.

The patching is done in index.js file which is the main file that loads the entire react UI.

Is there a way to be able to still call the unpatched method or somehow be able to replace the Authorization header in the XMLHttpRequest.

Apparently it does not seem like XMLHttpRequest has a way to unset or replace the headers. It has only one method called `setRequestHeaders` to append them.

I have thought in few different directions to solve this problem. Any advice on any of them or an alternate can be helpful.

1 - Try patching (patch2) the already patched (patch1) method with the original reference (original) and after use patch it back to the patch1 method. Not sure if it is possible to get the reference of the original from patch1 method.

2 - Save the original reference from index.js to some global context and change the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open to orginal momentarily while making the external call and reset it back.

3 - Find a way to unset and/or replace the header.

4 - Any other HTTP request library that does not use the XMLHttpRequest underneath. I am not sure that exists. I guess all libraries like fetch, axios, jquery ajax must be using XMLHttpRequest underneath.

Comment: I'd use the `xhrPrevOpen` variable, but it's a *very* X/Y problem

Comment: Is `xhrPrevOpen` a global variable or is this code inside an IIFE that makes it local?

Answer (score 0):

The situation is a bit unfortunate and **ideally the solution is to not patch the method in the first place**, but instead update the various calls that need to add that header so they do so (probably by calling a wrapper function).

**If you can't do that:**

I'd be tempted to edit `index.js` like so:

```
const token = ....
let xhrPrevOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (...a) {
    xhrPrevOpen.apply(this, [ ...a ]);
    this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
};
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.__rawopen__ = xhrPrevOpen; // <====
```

...then use `__rawopen__` instead of `open` in the cases where you don't want the patched `open`.

**Again**: Only if you really, really can't undo that awful patch of `open`.

---

> - Any other HTTP request library that does not use the XMLHttpRequest underneath. I am not sure that exists. I guess all libraries like fetch, axios, jquery ajax must be using XMLHttpRequest underneath.

I wouldn't assume that in the case of `fetch`, provided it's the native version provided by the browser. I would expect both `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` to use the same underlying internal features, rather than `fetch` *literally* using the exposed `XMLHttpRequest` that userland code can muck with. You might want to check in your target browsers to see if `fetch` really is affected by the change your code is making to `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open`. I suspect it isn't, which would give you another way around the problem.